# Triage queue review audit failure on a non-question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Failed triage queue [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/32307387) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904471/reported-critical-issues-with-version-17-0-0-google-play-warning) question.

The question has many upvotes and seems to touch a topic which is of interest for many people, however, in a way it's currently formulated there's no any *question* actually asked. Instead, a problem is described very briefly, after which a message from SDK developer is presented which could look like an answer. It seemed to me that this is either an answer-inside-question situation or the SDK developer response was not helpful, but it wasn't articulated *why* in the question.

So, I thought it needs clarification from the author, thus chose that the question needs an author edit, which resulted in a failed audit. So, is this a wrong audit or I misunderstand something?

Comment: It seems the question was fairly obvious to at least 3 users given they answered the question. There isn't a single comment asking the author, "what is your question?", seems like you failed an audit.  In the future you should open the question in another tab before selecting a response to a review.

Comment: @SecurityHound Isn't it discouraged to do this during review audits? After all, answers and question votes are masked on purpose so that they don't introduce bias.

Comment: Audits are designed to be passed.  You also can't cheat during a review of a contribution.  If they didn't want you to open the question, in another tab, they could disable the link to the question during the review.

Comment: @SecurityHound If they disabled the link to the question only for audits, it would reveal that review is an audit. If they disabled it for all reviews, interface would become less usable and it would make it harder to navigate to the question to do action unsupported by review interface (e.g. providing an answer). Also, if the question is intended to be always opened and viewed "really", then why is there masking during audit at all? To make reviewers distrust review interface?

Comment: I wouldn't call this the most clear question, but I do believe that it is answerable.

Answer (score 3):

For the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904471/reported-critical-issues-with-version-17-0-0-google-play-warning) it might be worth flagging because it doesn't help users reproduce the error, per [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Flag >> Needs Improvement >> Community Specific Reason >> Needs debugging details, maybe?

Also, the answer doesn't provide a reason why. The "Clarification from the author" flag is a good start but is also a bit generic. For what it's worth the flag was merited at least because markdown could be used to help showcase the error message. The system is automated though.